# wordpress as a cms photo gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, content-management-system, photo-gallery

So I am stripping down wordpress and using it as a simple photo/video gallery site. Basically each section has two types of pages: the gallery index (just thumbnail images), and the photo/video page itself.

The problem that arises is one of lazyness, I have a whole lot of photos and videos to add, and creating a new post for each item will be extremely tedious to say the least.

Is there an easy way to create a large number of posts at once, each with different content?

I'm thinking like a plugin or a script or some method I am as of yet, unaware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhotoBlogs are different from normal blogs. Normal blogs put the emphasis on the words with only the occasional image featured. PhotoBlogs are all about the images and not the words.

**The easiest way to get started** with photoblogging on WordPress is to either install Johannes Jarolim's [YAPB (yet another photo blog) plugin](http://johannes.jarolim.com/blog/wordpress/yet-another-photoblog/) or the [PhotoQ Photoblog plugin](http://www.whoismanu.com/photoq-wordpress-photoblog-plugin/).

YAPB adds all of the functionality of a standard photo blog directly to WordPress with a minimum of configuration. It includes automatic image resizing, exif data, and other tools. Johannes' site has [links to themes already incorporating YAPB](http://johannes.jarolim.com/blog/wordpress/yet-another-photoblog/ready-to-use-templates/), otherwise you can make your own.

PhotoQ takes a slightly different approach, it gives you a queue which you can fill with photos to be posted on your photoblog. PhotoQ is geared to batch processing of photos and it features batch uploads, automatic image resizing, exif support, watermarking and automatic posting via cronjobs among other features.

---

At last, if you don't like any, here is the list of [7 Superb Wordpress Photo Gallery Plugins](http://smartboydesigns.com/2009/05/08/7-superb-wordpress-photo-gallery-plugins/)

Comment: these are nice options, but I also want to be able to upload videos as well, so I guess I'd like to do this manually.